# Htaccess allow file access for given referrer not working

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

Please check below is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)://(www\.)?outlook.live.com [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule .*\.(wav|swf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

above code restrict direct access for the files (wav|swf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|js|css) if files are access through website then it allows it.

I have one issue is when I include image in the email and that image can not able to display in the email because of my htaccess restrictions. i need to allow that mail can display images. mail client includes (gmail,outlook,yahoo etc...) any suggestion.

Comment: Well, what referred do you see when looking at those requests?

Comment: Apart from that: I never understand why people try so desperately to prevent access to objects they publish. That is a contradiction. Why the effort?

Comment: @arkascha thanks for reply. i want to allow that all emails can display image. currently if i send any images in the email. email can not display image because of my htaccess restrictions so i want to allow emails to access my images.

Comment: You already wrote that in your question. Why do you repeat it instead of answering to the question I asked?

Comment: can you clarify your question ?

Comment: What is unclear about the question in my first comment? You get requests to images originating from E-Mail programs rendering html based emails you sent out. Currently you block those requests. You want to change that. Since you block requests based on the referrer you need to find out what referrer is set in those requests you do _not_ want to block. So take a look into your http server's access log file, that is where the referrer is logged for every request. What do you see for those requests?